# jquery .post method implies www prefix

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling a very basic jquery post method

```
$.post('/scripts/getid.php');
```

Jquery seems to be resolving this to https:// www.mysite.com/scripts/getid.php

However, my domain is mysite.com (no www.) and as such I'm getting a cross domain CORS error "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)".

If I supply the absolute url, this works fine but becomes messy when testing on different servers.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VPS Hosting using Plesk and it looks like Plesk got mixed up with my "Preferred domain". Despite this being set without www. subdomain Jquery post methods included the www. subdomain.

Switching to www.mysite.com as the preferred domain and then back to mysite.com has resolved this issue.